# Is it possible to make Django's syndb command NOT try to create actual foreign keys in the database?

Tags: django

I'm no Django expert, but from what I can gather, there is no way to tell syndb *not* to try to run ALTER statements to create foreign key constraints on the db.

I recently tried to upgrade my MySQL Cluster installation from 7.0.6 to the latest release 7.1.9a.  This revealed a bug in this latest MySQL release in which foreign key constructs are NOT ignored on engines that do not support them as they were in previous versions.  This is definitely a MySQL bug which I have submitted to them and they have verified as valid.

In the mean time, however, until that bug is fixed, I'm stuck running a very old version of MySQL and wondered if I could possibly work around it by somehow forcing syncdb NOT to try to actually create foreign keys on the database, just create the tables.

Without getting into detail, in my case the syncdb command is built into some automation that does a lot more than just build a database from models, so I can't very easily work around this manually.

Any input or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a table engine that supports them?

Answer (score 0):

South can do this (http://south.aeracode.org/)

You could do a schemamigration and then edit the migration by hand, leaving out the FK constructs. You could also make your own introspection rules in South that automates this, I guess. It might interfere with your syncdb automation, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can run python manage.py sqlall app_name, remove the ALTER FK constraints, and load the SQL manually.